# C# Calling WebApi method from MVC controller parameter is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a situation where I have an MVC Controller that I'm calling a WebApi POST method. I'm passing a DTO as a parameter... The WebApi method is hit, but the parameter is null. What am I missing?

Thanks!
MVC Controller:

```
     [Authorize]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        Permissions service = new Permissions();
        ViewBag.Title = "Deployment Manager";

        string uri = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiRestfulUrl"] + "/Permissions";
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var permissions = new PermissionsDTO() { UserName = "rherhut" };
            var response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync(uri, permissions);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                // Get response data how??
            }

        }

        return View();
    }
```

WebAPI POST Method:

```
     public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage request, [FromBody]PermissionsDTO permissions)
    {
         var data = repository.HasAdminRights(permissions.UserName); // permissions.UserName is null
        var response = new ApiResponseCreator<PermissionsDTO>();
        return response.FormatReturnData(request, data);
    }
```

Comment: Is permissions null as suggested in the question or is permissions.Username null as suggested in the code?

Comment: please also add code for your client which is calling this api method?

Comment: Sorry...permissions is NOT null, but permissions.UserName is null.

Comment: The code that is calling the WebApi controller is the first block of code in this post.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem by decorating the dto class with a "Serialize" attribute and for some reason this worked.